# Generics and Collections, don`t understand

Tags: java, generics, collections

Is there any difference between these 3 lines?

```
List list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
List  list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List  list2 = new ArrayList();
```

As I understand, all information about generics is erased in runtime. Consequently, only type of veriable is important. So the above lines of code mean the same thing to me. If I am wrong can anybody give me some exapmle that shows the difference?
 p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: I do not believe your second example is valid, as the `<>` operator will not have any information. It could be `List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime, but they exist at compilation time and let compiler detect many potential problems. In this case what you are using is raw type `List list2` which can accept any list, but because of that it is prone to many problems. More info: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: sorry, second line is wrong, my mistake. But anyway, I know about raw types, I am interested "in right part of expression". What the difference:
new ArrayList<String>();
  new ArrayList ();
I think the both mean the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is diamond Operator in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352816/what-is-diamond-operator-in-java)

Comment: @ViacheslavOn "What the difference: new ArrayList<String>(); new ArrayList (); " <- It is obvious you **don't** "know about raw types" otherwise you wouldn't ask that question. Because the difference between those two is that one is a raw type while the other isn't.

Comment: btw, second line is valid since Java 7

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS  what dont I understand? Raw types return Objects. If I use List list (raw type) any ArrayList will return Objects, wether it`s "new ArrayList<String>();" or just "new ArrayList();"   The same

Comment: See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: why don`t you understand that it doesn`t metter is there <> in right part of expression or not? You can`t give some example, because there is no such examples

Comment: raw types refers just to variables but not to certain instance

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that generic data is erased at *compile-time*, that doesn't mean they are totally useless. The only line that *would* compile in your example is the last one, but you would get a warning that you are using `RawType`s. A `RawType` is a generic class that does not have a generic object. The first two lines are only half-built.

The reason you pretty much *have* to use generics is that the list is type-safe. If you use generics, you could use something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String out = list.get(0);
```

If you use raw types, you would have to do this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
String out = (String) list.get(0);
```

This may seem OK, but what if you `add` a value to the list that is not a `String`? The program crashes. For example:

```
List unsafe = new ArrayList();
List<String> safe = new ArrayList<>();
unsafe.add("hi");
unsafe.add(new Tree());
safe.add("hi");
safe.add(new Tree());    // This line would throw an exception.
String out = (String) unsafe.get(0);
String out1 = safe.get(0);
String out2 = (String) unsafe.get(1);    // This line would throw an exception.
```

If you still don't quite see why to use generic types, the final nail in the coffin for raw types is this: If my `(String) unsafe.get(1)` is in a separate class, on the hundredth line, I know that *that* line is the problematic line. I, however, don't know where the non-string object is being added, only where it's being accessed.

If you use generic types, you know exactly where the problematic addition is made, and you can prevent it.

Comment: sorry, but all lines definitely compile and there is no any warnings.
And I know all that you have wrote, but it is not answer.

Comment: @ViacheslavOn If you don't think anything I wrote is the answer, then you don't seem to understand generic types, this video explains it better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tKmzQh8g5E

Comment: sorry, but all lines definitely compile and there is no any warnings.
And I know all that you have wrote, but it is not answer.
"A RawType is a generic class that does not have a generic object." - It is clear. But wheter class raw or not depends only on wheter reference is parametrized. And wheter object is parametrized or not It doesnt metter.

Comment: Watch the video, he provides more coherent and better-explained examples and reasons than I did. Even though the generic types are removed at compile-time, they are still extremely useful. And if for no other reason, you should use them because `RawTypes` only exist to be backwards compatible.

Comment: Why don`t I understand? You sad that 2 out of 3 lines wouldn`t complile. But all 3 would. So I guess we should start from this

Comment: No, that was an incorrect statement on my part. All generic lists can be cast to raw-lists. You could not, for example, have this: `List<String> list = new ArrayList();` while you can have: `List list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: To *directly* answer your question, *technically* the lines are different, but can be treated as the same. They are all `List`, so you could do the same things to all of them. None of them are generic lists however, not even the first one. They are all RawTypes

Comment: It is definitely answer that I was looking for.Because it is really doesn`t metter how I create ArrayList if my List is raw type. I was thinking that maybe I don`t understand something. And some people says that I don`t. But no one could say why