# getting "sub-LinkedLlists" from java's LinkedList class (for MergeSort purposes)

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to practice the *MergeSort* algorithm on java's standard *LinkedList*. I am new to standard libraries.

The issue I am having is creating 'sub-LinkedLists' to get the best performance from the *MergeSort*.

I have a working code, but unfortunately it treats the *LinkedList* as if it was some array:

```
public void mergeSort(LinkedList<Integer> lisst) {
    if (lisst.size() < 2){
        return;
    }    
    int middleindex  = lisst.size()/2;    
    LinkedList<Integer> LeftList = new LinkedList<Integer>();


    for(int i = 0; i< middleindex; i++){    
        LeftList.addLast(lisst.get(i));
    }
    mergeSort(LeftList);

    LinkedList<Integer> RightList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = middleindex; i< lisst.size(); i++){    
        RightList.addLast(lisst.get(i));    
    }

    mergeSort(RightList);
    SortedMerge(RightList,LeftList,lisst);    
}
```

From what I have been reading, doing sth like this, kills the purpose of merge sort on linkedlist. But how do I actually get sub linked lists with an object of the standard LinkedList class? I could do this confidently if it was sth I had written with a node class like :

```
node leftHead = lisst.get(middleindex);
mergeSort(lefthead);// Assuming the method also takes a node instead of LL
```

but reading the library, I can't figure out how to point to the middle element and use the rest as a sublist without looping over to add it to a new linked list

is there a really simple way to do this ? am I not seeing sth?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: You should pop all the nodes on the left of your sub-LinkedList.

Comment: Besides you should use [diamond expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) [whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352848/4927212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the right part of the `LinkedList`, you should have the following:

```
public static <T> LinkedList<T> removeUntil(LinkedList<T> list, int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        list.removeFirst();
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Usecase**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 3, 5, 6, 9}));
    System.out.format("Input : %s%n", list);
    list = removeUntil(list, 3);
    System.out.format("Output: %s%n", list);
}
```

**Usecase output**

```
Input : [1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
Output: [6, 9]
```

---

If you wish to reserve the left part of the `LinkedList`, you should have the following instead:

```
public static <T> LinkedList<T>[] split(LinkedList<T> list, int index) {
    LinkedList<T> left = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        T t = list.removeFirst();
        left.addLast(t);
    }

    return new LinkedList[] {
        left, list
    };
}
```

**Usecase**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 3, 5, 6, 9}));
    System.out.format("Input : %s%n", list);
    LinkedList[] alist = split(list, 3);
    System.out.format("Output: %s, %s%n", alist[0], alist[1]);
}
```

**Usecase output**

```
Input : [1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
Output: [1, 3, 5], [6, 9]
```

Reference:

- [LinkedList (Java Platform SE 8 API Reference)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: thanks. this actually helped me see it in a different way.