# Primefaces Dialog Framework and Parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, postconstruct

I am having trouble passing a parameter to a dialog that I can actually use.

I have a command button which is is set with an `actionListener` that calls an open dialog method in the backing bean

```
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("modal", true);
//...
options.put("includeViewParams", true);

Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("My String");
params.put("myParam", values);

PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("test", options, params);
```

then in my test page I gave

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="myParam" value="#{testBean.testVal}" />
</f:metadata>
...
<h:outputText value="#{testBean.testVal}" />
```

and the string is output fine.

But I want to use that value in to perform a database lookup and this just isn't working.

```
private String myParam;
private List<Object> myThings;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  myThings = service.lookup(myParam);
}
```

but in the `PostConstruct` call myParam is null.

I added some logging on `init` and the getter and setter and noticed I had

- init --> myParam null
- Getter --> myParam null
- Setter --> myParam = passed value
- Getter --> myParam = passed value
- Getter --> myParam = passed value

So it appears that the value is getting passed but after the `PostConstuct` method has fired.

An I doing something wrong or should I be doing this another way?  (I have seen reference of passing objects via the session map but is there a way of getting this working like this?)

Comment: Off topic; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352816/what-is-the-diamond-operator-in-java

Comment: Java is something I tend to not touch for ages and then have to get right into it again.   Tidying up code usually comes later...    Updated and will try and remember I can do that now.

Comment: Yes and in particular the linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id

Comment: Solution was to add `<f:viewAction action="#{testBean.init}" />` to the dialog page and remove the `@PostConstruct` annotation from init.