# Difference between specifying the generic type in the instantiation and not doing so

Tags: java, generics

From a practical point of view, is there a difference between this two lines?:

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();  

ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: functionally, none. point is, the declaration already sets the type, the instantiation will use that. List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); would be better, though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the diamond operator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352816/what-is-the-diamond-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. Java has a feature that is called "type inferring". It basically means that it checks if it can guess a type of a generic object. If you have a type assigned on the left side of the equation, java will guess the type on the right side. In compiled code, both statements look alike

Comment: This is what I was looking for, someone less lazy than me that would look at the byte code, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use this syntax:

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It's the same like:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

No any difference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it is just a third alternative.